# How to build a webform with custom fields in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-webform

I want to build a custom webform using webform module in drupal 7 but I want to use custom fields as form fields. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom fields"? What type of fields are you looking for?

Comment: I want to add the "field_first_name" to webform. And also I want all entered data to be stored in it. Please do not mind I am a newbie to Drupal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create your custom field as per requirement follow this awesome link.

http://jamestombs.co.uk/2012-09-24/create-new-webform-element-drupal-7

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a new piece of Webform content by going to Content > Add Content > Webform. Once you make your title, body, etc, click "Save" and you'll be taken to the next step of creating your form fields (called "Components"). In the components area, you can add whatever type of field you'd like, and all the submitted data will be stored in the "Results" area for that piece of content.

Comment: What if I want to add a custom field from which I can upload a file from admin area to attach it to a webform, which then I can make a force download to it after form submit? Any way of doing that?